# Clone a tree branch in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a well formed hierarchical tree in NEO4J 2.1, and I am trying to duplicate/clone a branch under another node in the tree, with Cypher. Is this feature supported in any way with a single query ?

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 /     \
d       e
```

would become

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 /   / \
d   d2  e
```

after cloning the "b" branch under the "c" branch. Note that i do not want to keep a relation between "b" and "d2"...

I have seen answer about "dump" command, but that does not fit my needs, since I need to do it in PHP.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not possible with Cypher.

I see two solutions for it right now for PHP :

**1 . Using export files**

With PHP you can execute shell commands, so you can place the dump + the cypher query to match the subtree you want in a file and load it with embedded shell command

neo4j-shell -file export.cql > result.txt

In the result.txt, this will be the result of the dump shell command, so the return cypher create statements, parse the file and execute a cypher query transaction.

**2. Using graph result data contents**

With the transactional cypher http endpoint, you can request your cypher match query in a graph format, this will return you nodes and relationships, you can easily recreate your self the cypher create statement to attach the subtree to another node. 
I created a quick proof example that do the job in a Gist : https://gist.github.com/ikwattro/eb7190f3f142ed591e0e

For my POV, the second solution is quite better, as you'll have more flexibility to modify the nodes before reinjecting them in the database, for example if you use a custom id strategy.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format

Chris
https://github.com/neoxygen